# Shortest common supersequence solver in JavaScript

Tags: gratis, open-source, javascript, node.js, algorithms

This question is closely related to [this one](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/25670/algorithm-to-merge-two-incomplete-sequences-of-symbols-strings-into-a-complete).

I am looking for a JavaScript implementation for a [Shortest common supersequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_common_supersequence) solver.

Do you have any pointers to libraries or other resources that contain a JavaScript implementation of it? (to be used in *node.js*).

Requirements:

- Free
- Open source

Comment: Any price/license?

Comment: @NicolasRaoul: 0/opensource

Comment: I couldn't find any JS library, but might be interested in porting implementations in other languages to JS: http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Shortest_common_supersequence